# Windows batch: formatted date into variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I save the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format into some variable in a Windows .bat file?

Unix shell analogue:

```
today=`date +%F`
echo $today
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows batch script format date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/windows-batch-script-format-date-and-time)

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php

Comment: adarshr, the answer to that question uses a quite horrible and error-prone way of dealing with it. I'd advise not to use it.

Comment: This link is helpful to understand the answers below. http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: [Split %date% in a batch file regardless of Regional Settings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15378719/995714)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can get the current date in a locale-agnostic way using

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
```

Then you can extract the individual parts using substrings:

```
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%
```

Another way, where you get variables that contain the individual parts, would be:

```
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
set today=%Year%-%Month%-%Day%
```

Much nicer than fiddling with substrings, at the expense of polluting your variable namespace.

If you need UTC instead of local time, the command is more or less the same:

```
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
set today=%Year%-%Month%-%Day%
```

Comment: One thing to note is that if you have a command prompt open while testing out this command, it will give you the time that you opened the command prompt (cmd.exe).  So if you have a command prompt open for a while and keep getting the same time, close and then re-open the command prompt.  If you're simply running a batch file from Windows Explorer, this won't be a problem.

Comment: @user2023861 It appears that even if I open a command prompt, I always get the correct date/time at the moment of invocation of the command, not when I had opened the command prompt.

Comment: Note that if you run the above line multiple times you won't get a new date for each invocation, as it checks for the variable being undefined. This is needed because `for /f` returns two lines, the latter of which being an empty one. You can solve that by using `set MyDate=` in between. I guess that's what user2023861 stumbled over.

Comment: Oh yes, I was just `echo`ing the wmic output, so it's always a fresh new date/time on every invocation. I seem unable to put it in the MyDate variable without doing `if not defined MyDate` first.

Comment: Man, the word needs to be spread about this method.  Having a locale-independent timestamp makes parsing easier and makes the batch file more robust (although I guess robustness is not really what people expect in a Windows batch file...).

Comment: @CharlesWood, at least I strive for robustness in my own batch files, although these days I often use PowerShell instead.

Comment: @Joey I know this is old, but is there a way to do this on a file to get the "Date Modified" in a similar format? Thanks.

Comment: Variables that will be set: `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Minute`, `Second`, `Quarter`, `WeekInMonth`, `DayOfWeek`

Comment: My god. I knew windows batch files were primitive but this is just ghastly. I found myself thinking about making a small batch file to automate creating audacity recording sessions named after the day, etc, but one look at the options of how to do it and I have decided to wait until I replace XP with Linux, hopefully in the new year.

Comment: @Majenko: You could just as well use VBScript or PowerShell. There are plenty of things to script in on Windows.

Comment: Power shell on XP? And I'd rather eat my own feet than dabble in VirusBasicScript.

Comment: `for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
set today=%Year%-%Month%-%Day%`  is invalid answer: it returns **one digit** month and day. How to get 2-digit left padded with zero month and day to date string ?

Comment: Andrus: If you need two digit months and days, then use the first solution proposed in this answer (with the substrings): wmic os get localdatetime outputs something like the following: LocalDateTime \ 20190824121817.349000+600 (the backslash is a carriage return). You could use the first eight characters of the second line as-is if you want a date in the format YYYYMMDD (i.e. set today=%MyDate:~0,8%).

Comment: Hi it works, thanks. One small question. How to have two digits months?

Comment: I ran the first command, but got this message "%%x was unexpected at this time." How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 49):

Use `date /T` to find the format on command prompt.

If the date format is `Thu 17/03/2016` use like this:

```
set datestr=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%
echo %datestr%
```

Comment: This is the closest answer to the asked question. A simple one-liner was all I needed, not a program.

Comment: Agreed.  Some of the answers here look almost like "Install MS SQL Server, connect with a SQL Client, and execute the command `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 112)`".

Comment: The date-time in ISO-8601 format is `%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%T%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%`

Comment: The reason that the other responses look like a program is that this answer, although simple, will fail if your Windows regional settings are not configured in the way that this code expects (i.e. this code will not work on *every* Windows system)

Answer (score 43):

If you wish to achieve this using standard MS-DOS commands in a batch file then you could use:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dd=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET yyyy=%%C
```

I'm sure this can be improved upon further but this gives the date into 3 variables for Day (dd), Month (mm) and Year (yyyy). You can then use these later in your batch script as required.

```
SET todaysdate=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
echo %dd%
echo %mm%
echo %yyyy%
echo %todaysdate%
```

While I understand an answer has been accepted for this question this alternative method may be appreciated by many looking to achieve this without using the WMI console, so I hope it adds some value to this question.

Comment: I found that I needed to change this slightly on a windows 7 box.
The tokens needed to be incremented by one:  

... FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3,4 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " ...

Comment: same on Win server 2012 on Azure

Comment: Sorry, this answer only works for some specific date format (not even sure which one), which is why comments above say it doesn't work.  The answers higher on the page work regardless of date format.

Comment: @iisystems The above works without modification for date format dd/mm/yyyy. To see how the output appears on your system just run DATE /T from the command line. It should be easy enough to switch the parameter order about to meet your requirements if you have a different date format for your region.

Comment: @JoeJohnston If you needed to increment your tokens by one it seems likely your system date settings are setup to include the day and so the day would be in the first token. It should be easy enough to tweak the token numbers though as you say. Unfortunately there does not appear to be any parameters to the date command to get it to output the date in a specific format, it's just returned according to your operating system preferences for short date format. You can use the same method to get the time if you switch DATE/T for TIME/T, it will be returned in your system's short time format.

Answer (score 23):

Two more ways that do not depend on the time settings (both taken from *[How get data/time independent from localization](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4555)*). And both also get the day of the week and none of them requires admin permissions!:

1. **MAKECAB** - will work on EVERY Windows system (fast, but creates a small temporary file) (the foxidrive script):

   ```
   @echo off
   pushd "%temp%"
   makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
   for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
       set "current-date=%%e-%%b-%%c"
       set "current-time=%%d"
       set "weekday=%%a"
   )
   del ~.*
   popd
   echo %weekday% %current-date% %current-time%
   pause
   ```
2. **ROBOCOPY** - it's not a native command for [Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) and [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003), but it can be [downloaded from the Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). But it is built-in in everything from Windows Vista and above:

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   for /f "skip=8 tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=: " %%D in ('robocopy /l * \ \ /ns /nc /ndl /nfl /np /njh /XF * /XD *') do (
       set "dow=%%D"
       set "month=%%E"
       set "day=%%F"
       set "HH=%%G"
       set "MM=%%H"
       set "SS=%%I"
       set "year=%%J"
   )

   echo Day of the week: %dow%
   echo Day of the month : %day%
   echo Month : %month%
   echo hour : %HH%
   echo minutes : %MM%
   echo seconds : %SS%
   echo year : %year%
   endlocal
   ```

   And three more ways that uses other Windows script languages. They will give you more flexibility e.g. you can get week of the year, time in milliseconds and so on.
3. **JScript/BATCH** hybrid (need to be saved as `.bat`). JScript is available on every system from [Windows NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) and above, as a part of [Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) ([though can be disabled through the registry it's a rare case](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198684.aspx)):

   ```
   @if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* ---Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

   @echo off
   cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
   exit /b 0
   *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   function GetCurrentDate() {
       // Today date time which will used to set as default date.
       var todayDate = new Date();
       todayDate = todayDate.getFullYear() + "-" +
                      ("0" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
                      ("0" + todayDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ("0" + todayDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                      ("0" + todayDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

       return todayDate;
   }

   WScript.Echo(GetCurrentDate());
   ```
4. **VBScript/BATCH** hybrid ([Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)) same case as jscript , but hybridization is not so perfect:

   ```
   :sub echo(str) :end sub
   echo off
   '>nul 2>&1|| copy /Y %windir%\System32\doskey.exe %windir%\System32\'.exe >nul
   '& echo current date:
   '& cscript /nologo /E:vbscript "%~f0"
   '& exit /b

   '0 = vbGeneralDate - Default. Returns date: mm/dd/yy and time if specified: hh:mm:ss PM/AM.
   '1 = vbLongDate - Returns date: weekday, monthname, year
   '2 = vbShortDate - Returns date: mm/dd/yy
   '3 = vbLongTime - Returns time: hh:mm:ss PM/AM
   '4 = vbShortTime - Return time: hh:mm

   WScript.echo  Replace(FormatDateTime(Date, 1), ", ", "-")
   ```
5. **PowerShell** - can be installed on every machine that has .NET - download from Microsoft ([v1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7217), [v2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929/bg), and [v3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) (only for Windows 7 and above)). Installed by default on everything form Windows 7/Win2008 and above:

   ```
   C:\> powershell get-date -format "{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm}"
   ```
6. **Self-compiled jscript.net/batch** (I have never seen a Windows machine without .NET so I think this is a pretty portable):

   ```
   @if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** silent line that start jscript comment ******

   @echo off
   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   :::       Compile the script    ::::
   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   setlocal
   if exist "%~n0.exe" goto :skip_compilation

   set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
   :: searching the latest installed .net framework
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
       if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
           rem :: the javascript.net compiler
           set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
           goto :break_loop
       )
   )
   echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
   :break_loop


   call %jsc% /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   :::       End of compilation    ::::
   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   :skip_compilation

   "%~n0.exe"

   exit /b 0


   ****** End of JScript comment ******/
   import System;
   import System.IO;

   var dt=DateTime.Now;
   Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
   ```
7. **Logman** This cannot get the year and day of the week. It's comparatively slow, also creates a temp file and is based on the time stamps that logman puts on its log files.Will work everything from Windows XP and above. It probably will be never used by anybody - including me - but it is one more way...

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   del /q /f %temp%\timestampfile_*

   Logman.exe stop ts-CPU 1>nul 2>&1
   Logman.exe delete ts-CPU 1>nul 2>&1

   Logman.exe create counter ts-CPU  -sc 2 -v mmddhhmm -max 250 -c "\Processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time" -o %temp%\timestampfile_ >nul
   Logman.exe start ts-CPU 1>nul 2>&1

   Logman.exe stop ts-CPU >nul 2>&1
   Logman.exe delete ts-CPU >nul 2>&1
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%t in  ('dir /b %temp%\timestampfile_*^&del /q/f %temp%\timestampfile_*') do set timestamp=%%t

   echo %timestamp%
   echo MM: %timestamp:~0,2%
   echo dd: %timestamp:~2,2%
   echo hh: %timestamp:~4,2%
   echo mm: %timestamp:~6,2%

   endlocal
   exit /b 0
   ```

[More information about the Get-Date function](http://ss64.com/ps/get-date.html).

---

Answer (score 13):

As per answer by @ProVi just change to suit the formatting you require

```
echo %DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%
```

will return

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
2015-09-15 18:36:11
```

**EDIT**
As per @Jeb comment, whom is correct the above time format will only work if your DATE /T command returns

```
ddd dd/mm/yyyy
Thu 17/09/2015
```

It is easy to edit to suit your locale however, by using the indexing of each character in the string returned by the relevant %DATE% environment variable you can extract the parts of the string you need.

eg. Using %DATE~10,4% would expand the DATE environment variable, and then use only the 4 characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded result

For example if using US styled dates then the following applies

```
ddd mm/dd/yyyy
Thu 09/17/2015

echo %DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%
2015-09-17 18:36:11
```

Comment: It's only a solution for some people, as this works only at some locations in the world, depending of your date/time format settings

Answer (score 8):

I really liked Joey's method, but I thought I'd expand upon it a bit.

In this approach, you can run the code multiple times and not worry about the old date value "sticking around" because it's already defined.

Each time you run this batch file, it will output an ISO 8601 compatible combined date and time representation.

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%D IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime') DO (SET LIDATE=%%D & GOTO :GOT_LIDATE)
:GOT_LIDATE
SET DATETIME=%LIDATE:~0,4%-%LIDATE:~4,2%-%LIDATE:~6,2%T%LIDATE:~8,2%:%LIDATE:~10,2%:%LIDATE:~12,2%
ECHO %DATETIME%
```

In this version, you'll have to be careful not to copy/paste the same code to multiple places in the file because that would cause duplicate labels. You could either have a separate label for each copy, or just put this code into its own batch file and call it from your source file wherever necessary.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to use PowerShell and redirect its output to an environment variable by using a loop.

From the command line (`cmd`):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('powershell get-date -format "{yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm}"') do set td=%a

echo %td%
2016-25-02+17:25
```

In a batch file you might escape `%a` as `%%a`:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell get-date -format "{yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm}"') do set td=%%a
```

Comment: Should mask be like this `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('powershell get-date -format "{yyyy\-MM\-dd\THH\:mm\:ss}"') DO SET date=%%a`  so use upper MM for month and backslash to escape literal characters.

Comment: This answer provides better support for systems configured using different "locales" that represent the date in different format by default, like dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 6):

This is an extension of Joey's answer to include the time and pad the parts with 0's.

For example, the result will be 2019-06-01_17-25-36. Also note that this is the UTC time.

```
  for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x

  set Month=0%Month%
  set Month=%Month:~-2%
  set Day=0%Day%
  set Day=%Day:~-2%
  set Hour=0%Hour%
  set Hour=%Hour:~-2%
  set Minute=0%Minute%
  set Minute=%Minute:~-2%
  set Second=0%Second%
  set Second=%Second:~-2%

  set TimeStamp=%Year%-%Month%-%Day%_%Hour%-%Minute%-%Second%
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `%date%` variable:

```
echo %date%
```

Comment: This will return the date in whatever the currently-configured short date format is. This is rarely ISO-8601.

Comment: @Joey Agreed - I'm here because this is not good enough to rely on.

Answer (score 3):

I set an environment variable to the value in the numeric format desired by doing this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %a IN ('echo %date%') DO set DateRun=%d-%b-%c
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this one..

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%" & set "MS=%dt:~15,3%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%-%MS%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to date and time format is location specific info, retrieving them from %date% and %time% variables will need extra effort to parse the string with format transform into consideration. A good idea is to use some API to retrieve the data structure and parse as you wish. WMIC is a good choice. Below example use [Win32_LocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394171(v=vs.85).aspx). You can also use [Win32_CurrentTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394114(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Win32_UTCTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394510(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
@echo off  
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION  
for /f %%x in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x  
set yyyy=0000%Year%  
set mmmm=0000%Month%  
set dd=00%Day%  
set hh=00%Hour%  
set mm=00%Minute%  
set ss=00%Second%  
set ts=!yyyy:~-4!-!mmmm:~-2!-!dd:~-2!_!hh:~-2!:!mm:~-2!:!ss:~-2!  
echo %ts%  
ENDLOCAL
```

Result:
2018-04-25_10:03:11

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following:

```
set iso_date=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%
```

Or in combination with a logfile name 'MyLogFileName':

```
set log_file=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-MyLogFileName
```

Comment: But where is your answer different or better than the other 16? And there are already enough hints, that this solution only works for your localization

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~4,2%
```

Comment: for output like this 20160711

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python installed, you can do

```
python -c "import datetime;print(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))"
```

You can easily adapt the format string to your needs.

Comment: In what way is saying "Use python" an answer to the question?

Comment: in the same way as using MAKECAB,  ROBOCOPY, VBSCRIPT, POWERSHELL Logman and other suggestions here that you can call on the command line?

Comment: This can be simplified to `python -c "import datetime;print(datetime.date.today())"`, because the `__str__` method of the `date` class just calls `isoformat()`.

Comment: It is quite different since Python is not a standard component of any Windows build. I can always call an arbitrary high level language runtime to get a fancy timestamp string to display but certainly it is not applicable to the majority of the environments.

Answer (score 0):

If powershell is available, you can use codes below:

```bsh
# get date
$BuildDate=(get-date -format "yyMMdd")
echo BuildDate=$BuildDate

# get time
$BuildTime=(get-date -format "hhmmss")
echo BuildTime=$BuildTime
```

Here is the result:

```
BuildDate=200518
BuildTime=115919
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind an one-time investment of 10 to 30 minutes to get a reliable solution (that doesn't depend on Windows' region settings), please read on.

Let's free our minds. Do you want to simplify the scripts to just look like this? (Assume you wants to set the LOG_DATETIME variable)

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`FormatNow "yyyy-MM-dd"`) DO (
  Set LOG_DATETIME=%%F
)

echo I am going to write log to Testing_%LOG_DATETIME%.log
```

You can. Simply build a FormatNow.exe with C# .NET and add it to your PATH.

Notes:

1. You can use any Visual Studio edition, such as Visual Studio Express, to build the FormatNow.exe.
2. In Visual Studio, choose the "Console Application" C# project, not "Windows Forms Application" project.
3. Common sense: the built FormatNow.exe will need .NET Framework to run.
4. Common sense: after adding FormatNow.exe to PATH variable, you need to restart CMD to take effect. It also applies to any change in environment variables.

Benefits:

1. It's not slow (finishes within 0.2 seconds).
2. Many formats are supported https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx
   e.g. FormatNow "ddd" to get only the day of week, FormatNow "yyyy" to get only the year
3. It doesn't depend on Windows' region settings, so its output is much more reliable. On the other hand, %date% doesn't give a consistent format over different computers, and is not reliable.
4. You don't need to create so many CMD variables and pollute the variable namespace.
5. It would require 3 lines in the batch script to invoke the program and get the results. It should be reasonably short enough.

Source code of FormatNow.exe which I built with Visual Studio 2010 (I prefer to build it myself to avoid the risk of downloading an unknown, possibly malicious program). Just copy and paste the codes below, build the program once, and then you have a reliable date formatter for all future uses.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace FormatNow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (args.Length < 1)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Missing format");
                }
                string format = args[0];
                Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In general, when dealing with complicated logics, we can make it simpler for by building a very small program and calling the program to capture the output back to a batch script variable instead. We are not students and we're not taking exams requiring us to follow the batch-script-only rule to solve problems. In real working environment, any (legal) method is allowed. Why should we still stick to the poor capabilities of Windows batch script that needs workarounds for many simple tasks? Why should we use the wrong tool for the job?