# bat file that gets current date in MMDDYY format and saves it in a variable for later use in the file

Tags: variables, date, batch-file

i am making a bat file that does a few tasks for me but i need to get the current date in MMDDYY format.

I know this will return the 4 digit year but how can i make it show 12 instead of 2012?
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c

Comment: possible duplicate: [windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945572/windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set MMDDYY=%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~12,2%`

check the return from `echo %DATE%` to see if you need to make adjustment for locale