# Windows CMD - How to create time variable with AM PM

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I create a variable in windows command line (CMD) that uses the following format:

**MON-DAY-YEAR_TIME-AM (or PM)**

```
set mon=%DATE:~4,2%
set day=%DATE:~7,2%
set yr=%DATE:~10,4%

> echo %mon%-%day%-%yr%
02-12-2018    # Good so far now I need to add time
```

Trying to set the output of TIME /T (10:54 AM) to a variable so I can use it with the date above. How can I do this?

```
> TIME /T
10:54 AM
```

Not what im looking for:

```
>set mytime=TIME /T

>echo %mytime%
TIME /T
```

Comment: [`%date%` is not a reliable way to get date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15378719/995714). And to get time just use `%time%`

Comment: to read stdout use [`for /f`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WMIC OS GET LOCALDATETIME` instead:

```bat
FOR /F "skip=1" %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET LOCALDATETIME') DO (SET "t=%%A" & GOTO break_1)
:break_1

SET "m=%t:~10,2%" & SET "h=%t:~8,2%" & SET "d=%t:~6,2%" & SET "z=%t:~4,2%" & SET "y=%t:~0,4%"
ECHO %z%-%d%-%y%_%h%:%m%
```

Output: `02-12-2018_17:27`

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

If you don't like the 24h format for whatsoever reason, use this:

```bat
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "skip=1" %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET LOCALDATETIME') DO (SET "t=%%A" & GOTO break_1)
:break_1
SET "m=%t:~10,2%" & SET "h=%t:~8,2%" & SET "d=%t:~6,2%" & SET "z=%t:~4,2%" & SET "y=%t:~0,4%"
IF !h! GTR 11 (SET /A "h-=12" & SET "ap=P" & IF "!h!"=="0" (SET "h=00") ELSE (IF !h! LEQ 9 (SET "h=0!h!"))) ELSE (SET "ap=A")

ECHO %z%-%d%-%y%_%h%:%m%-%ap%M
```

Output: `02-12-2018_05:27-PM`

---

And if you don't want an additional `0` in front of single digit hours, use this:

```bat
FOR /F "skip=1" %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET LOCALDATETIME') DO (SET "t=%%A" & GOTO break_1)
:break_1
SET "m=%t:~10,2%" & SET "h=%t:~8,2%" & SET "d=%t:~6,2%" & SET "z=%t:~4,2%" & SET "y=%t:~0,4%"
IF "%h%"=="00" (SET "h=0") ELSE (IF %h% LEQ 9 SET "h=%h:0=%")
IF %h% GTR 11 (SET /A "h-=12" & SET "ap=P") ELSE (SET "ap=A")

ECHO %z%-%d%-%y%_%h%:%m%-%ap%M
```

Output: `02-12-2018_5:27-PM`

Comment: Is it possible to get the AM/PM?

Comment: @jes516 If you refresh the page/post... ^^

Comment: @jes516 Had a small mistake in there, `12 AM` was `12 PM` and the other way around. Fixed it just now! :)

Comment: Both sets of your code output the leading zero for the hour

Comment: @Squashman Nope, the result of `SET /A "17-12"` is `5` and not `05`.

Comment: This is what I get for 9:15 AM `02-12-2018_09:15-AM 02-12-2018_09:15-AM`

Comment: With AM yes, as I don't need to makes use of `SET /A` (that's why the example has PM in it).

Comment: And 12:15 pm outputs this for both of them. `02-12-2018_00:15-PM`
`02-12-2018_0:15-PM`

Comment: @Squashman yep, it's ripped out of a bigger script of mine, forgot about the exclusions, will add them now! :)

Comment: The bottom version (the one that removes the leading zeros) no longer runs because it's missing the ending quote at the end of the set command on the fourth line. `(IF %h% LEQ 9 SET "h=%h:0=%)` should be `(IF %h% LEQ 9 SET "h=%h:0=%")`

Comment: I edited the final answer to fix the missing quote, and also use set/endlocal so that the calling environment doesn't get polluted with the temporary variables (minus the now resulting 'datetime'). This was mostly to get around the fact that I couldn't edit and add just one character =/ Feel free to change it however you want, and thanks for the script in general!

Comment: @BrentRittenhouse Thanks for your comment and edit suggestion; I fixed the missing quotation mark, but I don't think the mention of `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` is needed in this example as it is meant to be a code snippet only and it's not essential for it to work. :)

Comment: @FatalBulletHit, agreed. Like I said, it was mostly to get around the fact that I couldn't do such a simple edit. Your code was fantastic as-is. If anyone wants to see a 'setlocal' version they can always go back through the edits anyway, right? Seriously, thank you very much for the awesome snippet! It's something I've used on multiple occasions. edit: Looks like you removed the history. Doesn't matter. People can modify it as needed. Have a great day!

Comment: @BrentRittenhouse I didn't remove the history, propably was automated. Also, glad I could help, have a nice one, too! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another reliable and locale independent way would be to use PowerShell.

```
FOR /F %%t IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-Date -UFormat '%I:%M %p'"') DO (
    SET "mytime=%%t"
)

ECHO %mytime%
```

Comment: trying to stay away from powershell for this particular script. for whatever reason powershell does not play nice when copying files that are actively being written to. even when calling robocopy from within powershell sometimes just hangs which is why im moving them over to batch scripts. i have a powershell script going in after and zipping the files and removing the originals.

Comment: I do not see how using a cmd.exe .bat script will do anything better when copying files that are still being written. Good luck with your choice.

Comment: I didnt say it was better. Is it common practice to call cmd commands from within powershell? That powershell script i have does not complete for me through task scheduler. Manually it runs. Exploring all options...

Comment: When necessary, it is fine to call other executables from PowerShell. See the `&` invocation operator.