# Batch Script - ECHO /set time not working- Win Server 2012

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script like below, it was working in our old server(2008), but when I moved it to new one it cannot update %d%:

```
rem @echo off 
@set path=c:\test;%path%

@set d=%date:~-4,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~-7,2% 
@set d=%d: =_% 
@set t=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2% @set t=%t: =0%

Rem  Generate PGP encrypted file 
@echo Starting PGP... >> c:\apps\ftpLogs\test.log 
gpg2 --batch --yes -r testkey --output c:\test\foo\test_%d%.pgp --encrypt c:\test\foo\test_%d%.txt >> c:\apps\ftpLogs\test.log
```

When I am changing the %d% to today' date, the pgp and every thing works well , but in case of using %d% it's bypassing these lines. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: echo %date% on both machines and see if the format is the same. Date format varies by country.

Comment: that was the reason I said echo is not working as well, when I do echo %date% it will give me %date% as the answer. But the old server, is giving 05/05/2015 as the result of 'echo %date%'

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945572/windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extensions disabled on the new server. Try

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions
    echo %date%
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with an unambiguous date format as per [Working with Dates and Times using WMI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198928.aspx).

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%G in (
    'wmic os get localdatetime/value'
) do @set "localdatetime=%%~G"
echo %localdatetime%
```

It should display something alike to `20150505222428.137000+120`, which is the date displayed in the Universal Time Coordinate (UTC) format.

In the UTC format, dates are displayed as `yyyymmddHHMMSS.xxxxxx±UUU`, where:

```
yyyy   represents the year.
mm     represents the month.
dd     represents the day.
HH     represents the hour (in 24-hour format).
MM     represents the minutes.
SS     represents the seconds.
xxxxxx represents the milliseconds.
UUU    represents the difference, in minutes, between   
                      the local time zone and Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
```

Example:

```
20150505222428.137000+120
yyyymmddHHMMSS.xxxxxx±UUU
```