# Windows script for copying modified files

Tags: windows, file, copy

I tried to write a script that copies modified files from my development environment to a desktop folder, but it copies all of the files, not just the modified ones. This is the script:

```
set codeFolder=C:\Dev\tsg-bto-apps-lt-pc-trunk

FOR /F "TOKENS=1 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dayOfWeek=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%C
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3,4 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET yyyy=%%D

SET today=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%

Xcopy /Y /D:%today% /I %codeFolder%\bin C:\Users\sheaffer\Desktop\testFolder
```

The method is as follows:

1. Get today's date (I used the method that appears in the second answer in the following link: [Windows batch: formatted date into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945572/windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable)).
2. Use Xcopy with the /D flag (there is an example in the following link: http://www.windows-commandline.com/xcopy-command-syntax-examples/)

I can't see what I am doing wrong. The result is that all of the files in my bin folder are copied, and not just files that have been modified today. When I run my script, the command that is generated is:

`Xcopy /Y /D:04-11-15 /I C:\Dev\tsg-bto-apps-lt-pc-trunk\bin C:\Users\sheaffer\Desktop\testFolder`

Please help me understand my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't insist on using xcopy, I'd recommend using robocopy.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks. I took your advice and rewrote the script using robocopy. It works, and the new script is simpler because I can use `/maxage:1` and avoid string/date manipulation. I am still curious about why the script I posted doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help for xcopy says the /D date format is m-d-y and you have your date in d-m-y format. You're saying copy all files changed on or after Apr 11, 2015.  Also robocopy is better than xcopy . Really long path names that trip up xcopy

Answer (score 0):

I took Filburt's advice and used robocopy instead of xcopy and it works. The new script is simpler because I can use `/maxage:1` and avoid string/date manipulation.

```
set codeFolder=C:\Dev\tsg-bto-apps-lt-pc-trunk

robocopy %codeFolder%\bin C:\Users\sheaffer\Desktop\testFolder /MAXAGE:1
```