# Get a two-digit hour when renaming a file with a time stamp in Windows command-line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, timestamp, rename

I want to make sure my renaming command always puts the hours as two digits.  So even if it is 9:30 AM, I want the filename to add 0930 at the end.  Altering the code below, how can I accommodate this?

```
ren c:\progra~1\tsi\edata\advantis\edisave\Dillards\846_Temp\001_846_tmp.txt "001_846_tmp_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt"

ren c:\progra~1\tsi\edata\advantis\edisave\Dillards\846_Print\001_846_prt.txt "001_846_prt_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt"
```

Comment: Never mind!  This solved my issue!  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984391/cmd-line-rename-file-with-date-and-time/18786818#18786818