# Batch file to rename a file when the filename is a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found the base code for this here already and was using it to move and then rename a file where I knew the file name.  However, now I would like to move a file where the file name is a parameter.

When I run this code it renames the folder with the current date and time. How do I get it to rename the variable file name in the folder?  I added the pause to try and troubleshoot what was happening.

```
Echo Off
SET SiteName=%~1
SET FileDate=%~2
SET File=%SiteName%%FileDate%  


IF Not EXIST C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report\%File%  GOTO DoNothing

copy C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report\%File%    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report_Archive\%File% 


ren C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report_Archive\%File% %SiteName%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_@_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.csv
ren C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report_Archive\%File% %SiteName%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_@_%time:~1,1%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.csv


del C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report\%File%
pause

:DoNothing
Exit
```

Comment: You are trying to rename the same file twice, which of course cannot work (upon the first renaming, the source path does no longer exist); so what do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use double quotes, like this:

```
Echo Off
SET "SiteName=%~1"
SET "FileDate=%~2"
SET "File=%SiteName%%FileDate%"


IF Not EXIST "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report\%File%" GOTO DoNothing

copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report\%File%" "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report_Archive\%File%" 

ren "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report_Archive\%File%" "%SiteName%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_@_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.csv"
ren "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report_Archive\%File%" "%SiteName%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_@_%time:~1,1%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.csv"


del "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\~Withdrawal_Report\%File%"
pause

:DoNothing
Exit
```

Also, you're trying to rename the same file twice, as far as I can tell. Did that work before?

Comment: You should also use `""` around the `set` expressions like `set "SiteName=%~1"`, because otherwise, several special characters in the arguments may cause trouble...

Comment: Thank you Dennis and aschipfl!  Adding the quotes around the entire file path worked.  The whole renaming of the file twice was for the single digit/double digit (Hour) timestamp.  One of the renames will fail it is is a single digit hour, and vice versa for a double digit hour. This is the base code, where it is explained. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984391/cmd-line-rename-file-with-date-and-time